# Waiting for a task inside a thread pool using SwingWorker java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, swingworker

I'm simulating multiple Tasks inside a thread - when all of them should report to a GUI. So I have a unique form that has 4 Panels inside which should reply and do different Tasks.. they should each keep pooling a database and reporting stuff to the GUI. In this example, I just made it to write numbers to a textArea.

```
public class FormMain extends JFrame {
    private JButton btnStart;
    private JPanel _panelTop, _panelMid, _panelBot;

    private PanelFoo panelFooA, panelFooB, panelFooC, panelFooD;

    private final List<String> ugsRj = Arrays.asList("AB");
    private final List<String> ugsMg = Arrays.asList("CD", "EF");
    private final List<String> ugsBA = Arrays.asList("GH", "IJ", "KL");
    private final List<String> ugsPE = Arrays.asList("MN", "OP", "RS", "TU");

    private void initialize() {
        this._panelTop = new JPanel();
        this._panelMid = new JPanel();
        this._panelBot = new JPanel();

        this.btnStart = new JButton("Start");
        this._panelBot.add(this.btnStart);

        this.panelFooA = new PanelFoo(this.ugsRj);
        this.panelFooB = new PanelFoo(this.ugsMg);
        this.panelFooC = new PanelFoo(this.ugsBA);
        this.panelFooD = new PanelFoo(this.ugsPE);
        _panelMid.setLayout(new BoxLayout(_panelMid, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        this._panelMid.add(this.panelFooA);
        this._panelMid.add(this.panelFooB);
        this._panelMid.add(this.panelFooC);
        this._panelMid.add(this.panelFooD);

    }

    public FormMain() {
        initialize();
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(800, 516);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().add(this._panelTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(this._panelMid, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(this._panelBot, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        this.btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                final AuthenticationUser auth = new AuthenticationUser();
                auth.setUser("test");
                auth.setPassword("p@ss");
//
                final SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        final WorkerDoSomething w1 = new WorkerDoSomething(panelFooA);
                        w1.addPropertyChangeListener(new ProgressListener(panelFooA.getProgressBar()));
                        final WorkerDoSomething w2 = new WorkerDoSomething(panelFooB);
                        w2.addPropertyChangeListener(new ProgressListener(panelFooB.getProgressBar()));
                        final WorkerDoSomething w3 = new WorkerDoSomething(panelFooC);
                        w3.addPropertyChangeListener(new ProgressListener(panelFooC.getProgressBar()));
                        final WorkerDoSomething w4 = new WorkerDoSomething(panelFooD);
                        w4.addPropertyChangeListener(new ProgressListener(panelFooD.getProgressBar()));

                        w1.execute();
                        w2.execute();
                        w3.execute();
                        w4.execute();

                        return null;
                    }

                };
                worker.execute();
            }
        });

    }
}

public class ProgressListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
    private JProgressBar bar;

    ProgressListener() {
    }

    ProgressListener(final JProgressBar b) {
        this.bar = b;
        this.bar.setValue(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        // Determine whether the property is progress type
        if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            this.bar.setValue((int) evt.getNewValue());
        }
    }
}

public class PanelFoo extends JPanel {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1400188281877395934L;
    private JLabel label;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JScrollPane scrollPanel;
    private JProgressBar progressBar;

    public PanelFoo(final List<String> listOfStates) {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(180, 400);
        final ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("/images/waiting-list.png", "waiting start");
        this.label = new JLabel(listOfStates.get(0), icon, SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
        add(this.label);

        this.textArea = new JTextArea("Numbers: \n");
        this.textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        this.scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(this.textArea);
        this.scrollPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 350));

        this.progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);

        add(this.scrollPanel);
        add(this.progressBar);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    /** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
    public ImageIcon createImageIcon(final String path, final String description) {
        if (path != null) {
            ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));
            final Image image = imageIcon.getImage(); 
            final Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(30, 30, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            imageIcon = new ImageIcon(newimg, description);
            return imageIcon;

        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public final JLabel getLabel() {
        return this.label;
    }

    public final void setLabel(final JLabel label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public final JTextArea getTextArea() {
        return this.textArea;
    }

    public final void setTextArea(final JTextArea textArea) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    public final JProgressBar getProgressBar() {
        return this.progressBar;
    }

    public final void setProgressBar(final JProgressBar progressBar) {
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
    }

}

public class WorkerDoSomething extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

    private JTextArea txtArea;
    private JLabel label;
    private Random r = new Random();

    WorkerDoSomething() {
    }

    public WorkerDoSomething(final PanelFoo panelFooInstance) {
        this.txtArea = panelFooInstance.getTextArea();
        this.label = panelFooInstance.getLabel();
    }

    private Integer randomInt(final int min, final int max) {
        final Integer randomNumber = this.r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

        return randomNumber;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        final Integer randomNumber = randomInt(10000000, 1000000000);
        long j;
        int progress = 0;
        final int onePerCent = randomNumber / 100;
        final int onePerMillion = onePerCent / 10;
        for (j = 0; j <= randomNumber; j++) {
            if (j % onePerCent == 0) {
                progress = (int) j / onePerCent;
                setProgress(progress);
            }
            if (j % onePerMillion == 0) {
                publish(j);
            }
            //Thread.sleep(randomInt(1000, 5000));
        }
        

        return null;
    }

    private void publish(final long num) {
        this.txtArea.append(num + "\n");
        this.txtArea.setCaretPosition(this.txtArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }

}
```

This is the main GUI after all:

[image: Main Gui]

and this is the execution:

[image: Running without sleep]

I just need to wait for a time on each `WorkerDoSomething`'s task, adding that line (previously comment out): `Thread.sleep(randomInt(1000, 5000));`

but when I do.. the whole execution freezes, of course..because it uses a single thread to run all the tasks - I suppose.

[image: Running with sleep]

Is there a solution for this?

Oh...I have to use java 1.8 in the business:

```
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

The whole project it's on my personnal [git](https://github.com/marllon/java-multi-task-swing)

--- first edit with debug perspective

[image: debug]

Comment: I think you should look at this in a debugger, tell us which threads are blocked, and on what object or condition the threads are blocked.  It's not obvious to me what is going on.

Comment: all of them it's running... just added a print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution is not freezing since Swing uses a thread pool of 10 threads to run the workers.
You can see it work properly if you comment out this part:

```java
if (j % onePerMillion == 0) {
    publish(j);
}
```

PS - Why do you create a new SwingWorker in the actionPerformed method?
Why not simply write like this:

```java
    this.btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        final WorkerDoSomething w1 = new WorkerDoSomething(panelFooA);
        w1.addPropertyChangeListener(new ProgressListener(panelFooA.getProgressBar()));
        final WorkerDoSomething w2 = new WorkerDoSomething(panelFooB);
        w2.addPropertyChangeListener(new ProgressListener(panelFooB.getProgressBar()));
        final WorkerDoSomething w3 = new WorkerDoSomething(panelFooC);
        w3.addPropertyChangeListener(new ProgressListener(panelFooC.getProgressBar()));
        final WorkerDoSomething w4 = new WorkerDoSomething(panelFooD);
        w4.addPropertyChangeListener(new ProgressListener(panelFooD.getProgressBar()));

        w1.execute();
        w2.execute();
        w3.execute();
        w4.execute();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Yeah...that's correct. Nothing was wrong, actually. I just had to remove the if you mentioned. awkward.

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the *javadoc* for class [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)? Here is an excerpt:

> Class SwingWorker<T,V>
> Type Parameters:
> T - the result type returned by this SwingWorker's doInBackground and get methods
> V - the type used for carrying out intermediate results by this SwingWorker's publish and process methods

You correctly call method `publish()` in your `doInBackground()` method, but you have not overridden method `process()`. Refer to [Tasks that Have Interim Results](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html). Assuming that your `publish()` method is really supposed to be the `process()` method, then this should be the declaration of class `WorkerDoSomething`

```java
public class WorkerDoSomething extends SwingWorker<Void, Long> {
```

And this should be method `process()` (instead of method `publish()`)

```java
protected void process(List<Long> nums) {
    this.txtArea.append(nums.get(nums.size() - 1) + "\n");
    this.txtArea.setCaretPosition(this.txtArea.getDocument().getLength());
}
```

But doing that will not solve your problem. I can't explain why but the problem is resolved if you change the location of the call to `Thread.sleep()` in method `doInBackground()`. If I place the call to method `sleep()` immediately before the call to `setProgress()`, then the GUI does not "freeze". I got the idea to move the location of the call to sleep from [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Swing_How_to/SwingWorker/Put_lengthy_task_in_SwingWorker.htm) Web page, entitled *Java Swing How to - Put lengthy task in SwingWorker*

Here is my rewrite of your application. I took the liberty to rewrite parts of it, but essentially you just need to pay attention to the `WorkerDoSomething` class.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class FormMain implements Runnable, ActionListener {
    private static final int  PANELS = 4;
    private static final String  START = "Start";

    private JFrame  frame;
    private PanelFoo[]  fooPanels;

    public FormMain() {
        fooPanels = new PanelFoo[PANELS];
        for (int i = 0; i < PANELS; i++) {
            fooPanels[i] = new PanelFoo();
        }
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.ActionListener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();
        switch (actionCommand) {
            case START:
                start();
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                              actionCommand,
                                              "Unhandled",
                                              JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        createGui();
    }

    private JButton createButton(String text, int mnemonic, String tooltip) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
        button.setToolTipText(tooltip);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        return button;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.add(createButton(START, KeyEvent.VK_S, "Start your engines!"));
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private void createGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 4, 10, 10));
        for (PanelFoo pf : fooPanels) {
            mainPanel.add(pf);
        }
        return mainPanel;
    }

    private void start() {
        for (PanelFoo pf : fooPanels) {
            pf.start();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new FormMain());
    }
}

class PanelFoo extends JPanel implements PropertyChangeListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4029040375048696554L;

    private JProgressBar  progressBar;
    private JTextArea  textArea;

    public PanelFoo() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        textArea = new JTextArea(20, 10);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        add(progressBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    public void appendText(String text) {
        textArea.append(text);
        textArea.append("\n");
    }

    @Override // java.beans.PropertyChangeListener
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            int progress = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
            progressBar.setValue(progress);            
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        WorkerDoSomething worker = new WorkerDoSomething(this);
        worker.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
        worker.execute();
    }
}

class WorkerDoSomething extends SwingWorker<Void, Long> {
    private PanelFoo  fooPanel;
    private Random r = new Random();

    public WorkerDoSomething(PanelFoo pf) {
        fooPanel = pf;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Integer randomNumber = randomInt(10000000, 1000000000);
        long j;
        int progress = 0;
        final int onePerCent = randomNumber / 100;
        final int onePerMillion = onePerCent / 10;
        for (j = 0; j <= randomNumber; j++) {
            if (j % onePerCent == 0) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException xInterrupted) {
                    // Ignore
                }
                progress = (int) j / onePerCent;
                setProgress(progress);
            }
            if (j % onePerMillion == 0) {
                publish(j);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Long> numbers) {
        Long number = numbers.get(numbers.size() - 1);
        fooPanel.appendText(String.valueOf(number));
    }

    private Integer randomInt(final int min, final int max) {
        final Integer randomNumber = this.r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        return randomNumber;
    }
}
```

I would say that technically, the above answers your question, which was:

> Is there a solution for this?

I believe I have provided a solution, even if I can't explain why it works.

Comment: thanks for your help! Actually I really need'em to do "nothing" (void). As I mentioned I'm going to pooling a database periodically. so... thanks anyways

Comment: @MarllonNasser so you're saying that you didn't need to call method `publish()` and therefore you didn't need to override method `process()`. Is that correct?

Comment: yes! In fact I'd need a custom method just to update/insert text inside the textArea. In the final version I wont override them.